# I'm having trouble trying to edit my product. Before it was working but it wasn't saving. Now it's no longer saving, let alone editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble trying to edit my product. Before it was working but it wasn't saving. Now it's no longer saving, let alone editing.
I've tried everything, but I can't succeed. I have 2 models of products, one is the product and the other productinsert. The difference is that the "product" is just for consultation, while the "productinsert" would be to create a new product, since it has some attributes that the do get does not have.

**My Code(Update):**

```
public async Task<Product> Update(string products, ProductInsert product, RootobjectInsert root)
            {
            ProductInsert produtocriado = new ProductInsert();
            produtocriado.sku = products;

            RootobjectInsert raiz = new RootobjectInsert()
            {
                    product = new ProductInsert()
                {
                    sku = product.sku,
                    active = product.active,
                    price = product.price,
                    qty = product.qty
                }
            };
            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br")
            };
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@test.com.br");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "app/Api/V1/Products/" + product.sku);

                string jsonObjeto = JsonSerializer.Serialize(raiz);
                req.Content = new StringContent(jsonObjeto, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
                //res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var roots = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(responseBody);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return null;
        }
        }
    }
```

**My controller:**

```
 // GET: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string product)
        {
            var products = await _IProduto.GetOne(product);
            return View(products);

        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(string products, ProductInsert product, RootobjectInsert root)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Update(products, product, root);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

[image: Error edit(update)]

**Edit 2:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebConsumoApi.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Criar Novo Produto</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sku)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.qty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.list_price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_gross)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_liquid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.height)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.width)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.length)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.items_per_package)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.brand)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ean)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td height="10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sku)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.qty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.weight_gross)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.weight_liquid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.height)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.width)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.length)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.items_per_package)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ean)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { product = item.sku }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { product = item.sku }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { product = item.sku })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates that there is type mismatch on the model. ViewDataDictionary requires a model instance of type ProductInsert.

If the view needs to work with an instance of Product, define it accordingly.

Comment: But everything is already with "ProductInsert", but I don't understand why the error

Comment: Can you please include the implementation of the index method?

Comment: In edit 2 is my index, which shows the list of products. I'm just getting the "sku" of my product for the edit page.